# "Dependency (AJAX)" in Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

About 50% of our data points logged are "Dependency (AJAX)".

Where does this come from ?

I think these "Dependency (AJAX)" began to show up after I enabled Web sockets in the Application Settings of my web app (we are using signalr).

The Property "Command" of these data points have a value of "/signalr/ping", so this definitely has something to do with signalr.

I would like to exclude those, as it's using too much of my free plan available data points.

Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule is already disabled in my ApplicationInsights.config.

**EDIT**

I tried to disable Web sockets, but still getting those logs.

**EDIT 2016-02-24**

As suggested by Alex, I set disableAjaxTracking:true, but it didn't help.

Here is the appInsights code in the `<head>` of my html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var appInsights = window.appInsights || function (config) {
        function r(config) { t[config] = function () { var i = arguments; t.queue.push(function () { t[config].apply(t, i) }) } } var t = { config: config }, u = document, e = window, o = "script", s = u.createElement(o), i, f; for (s.src = config.url || "//az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js", u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(s), t.cookie = u.cookie, t.queue = [], i = ["Event", "Exception", "Metric", "PageView", "Trace"]; i.length;) r("track" + i.pop()); return r("setAuthenticatedUserContext"), r("clearAuthenticatedUserContext"), config.disableExceptionTracking || (i = "onerror", r("_" + i), f = e[i], e[i] = function (config, r, u, e, o) { var s = f && f(config, r, u, e, o); return s !== !0 && t["_" + i](config, r, u, e, o), s }), t
    }({
        instrumentationKey: "@Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey",
        disableAjaxTracking: true
    });
    window.appInsights = appInsights;
    appInsights.trackPageView();
</script>
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <script>
        appInsights.setAuthenticatedUserContext("@User.Identity.Name".replace(/[,;=| ]+/g, "_"));
    </script>
}
```

Comment: We currently have the same issue here, busting the free tier because of 5.3 millions dependency data-point generated by the ping of SignalR. I'll keep you post if I found something on my site.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from the end of December 2015 Application Insights JavaScript SDK is automatically collecting AJAX requests. Here's a [blog post about it](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/ajax-collection-in-application-insights/).
Since its enablement we also introduced a maximum cap of AJAX requests that can be logged per page view, the default is 500, but you can change this setting by adding this property to your snippet (more on this in the blog and linked documentation):

```
maxAjaxCallsPerView: <number>
```

You can also disable AJAX request collection alltogether by using this setting:

```
disableAjaxTracking: true
```

EDIT: looks like disableAjaxTracking is broken as of 2/24/2016, until it is fixed, the mitigation is to use

```
maxAjaxCallsPerView: 0
```

Comment: I tried set disableAjaxTracking:true, but still see all those "Dependency (AJAX)"

Comment: Does your website have a public facing URL, so we can try to diagnose if Ajax's are still being collected?

Comment: No sorry, the site need authentication, and the login page has no appInsights integration. I did update my question with the javascript appInsights code if it can help.

Comment: I would like to confirm, that remote dependencies are indeed being sent from your browser.Can you please use browser tools like F12 or Fiddler to capture network payload sent to dc.services.visualstudio.com and ensure that remote dependencies are indeed present in this payload. For example,this is a screenshot I took from a website that is sending ajax's to AI: https://ovjwdq.dm2303.df.livefilestore.com/y3m8UmbClTzW78KOBCpxg5vuj6IdpuaizhibMTZcSBm42ajrdSdKOhBeBa-iVY9I-g63TthR1tpCtwJHZJ7EExZDiL9RwEwKLN-zAD0e1xL_h7EzFgWzJPA0DDcJl3k-F50r2zJKHWSY_yNQUIfunacqTVNSdyiU2BsRk0if-GCCfE/rdddata.png?psid=1

Comment: Yes I can see a POST being made to dc.services.visualstudio.com, containing many "RemoteDependencyData"

Comment: Hmm, I could also reproduce this issue, looks like this switch was broken. As mitigation can you please use the following flag instead:  maxAjaxCallsPerView: 0, until disableAjaxTracking flag is fixed. Thanks for spotting this problem!

Comment: Can you confirm what's the sdkVersion being reported (in the browser's Network trace you showed) - look at tags -> ai.internal.sdkVersion

Comment: ai.internal.sdkVersion: "JavaScript:0.22.4"

Comment: Sorry for the back and forth - looks like I can no longer repro the issue - if you can still repro, can you please share a simple page with JS snippet and some AJAX call. Here's a JS Fiddle, where I cannot repro the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/2chj4meh/

Comment: Using maxAjaxCallsPerView:0 did work, however i get this warning several times in the logs: AI: USRACT_MaxAjaxPerPVExceeded message:"Maximum ajax per page view limit reached, ajax monitoring is paused until the next trackPageView(). In order to increase the limit set the maxAjaxCallsPerView configuration parameter."  I will try switch back to disableAjaxTracking on my next deploy.

Comment: Thanks! Please try it and let us know if you are still having the issue with disableAjaxTracking - several people tried to repro and couldn't.